# How to configure AP priority in netplan?

Tags: networking, ubuntu-18.04, netplan

I would like to configure more than one AP in netplan,
like this:

```
wifis:
   wlan0:
       access-points:
           network1:
               password: "abc"
               priority: 0
           network2:
               password: "def"
               priority: 1
```

I would like to set a priority to those networks in order to prefer one over the other if available. E.g.: Use `network1` if available, otherwise `network2`.

Is that possible? Maybe the order is the way to define the priority?

Couldn't find anything on netplan.io :/

Comment: I tried doing the same thing in ubuntu 23.04, I am surprised it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Such a boring answer, but if you want to force connect to a specific wifi network. One easy solution is to comment out the other network the other networks.

```
bash$ history
...
 2077  sudo vim /etc/netplan/*.yaml 
 2078  sudo netplan apply 
 2079  sudo netplan status
```